# Returning a value in Pascal

Tags: pascal, freepascal

For a function to return a value in Pascal the assignment `FunctionName := SomeVal;` is used. I assume it doesn't stop the function execution in that exact place as `return` in C does. Is there something similar to C `return` in Pascal? (I'm using FreePascal compiler)

Comment: Just FYI: The `FunctionName := SomeVal;` syntax is antiquated; the current syntax is `Result := SomeVal;`, where `Result` is an automatically available variable of the proper data type to match the function declaration. For instance: `function Test: Integer; begin Result := 10; end;`.

Comment: Ken White: In Free Pascal, result is afaik only supported in Delphi and delphi-like dialects. (-S2/-Sd). Other pascal's haven't adopted the Delphi centric result either, or only for compatibility modes. The last Pascal standard still documents this

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use the Exit procedure.

```
function Foo (Value : integer) : Integer;
begin      
  Exit(Value*2);
  DoSomethingElse();   // This will never execute
end;
```

Comment: +1, never heard about this syntax! However might be good to put a line after the `Exit` with some comment that the line after `Exit` won't be performed.

Comment: +1 this is a nice syntax, helps to avoid the dreaded Result + Exit combo. Basically the equivalent of "return".

Answer (score 1):

The return code of the end of every program is stored in the EAX register. So you can use Assembly inline on Pascal to return wherever you want to end the program running using!

```
 asm
 mov eax,%ERROLEVEL%
 end;
```

Comment: That's what you compiler will do after the compilation! Followed by a RET

Comment: Using inline-assembly is not cross-platform compatible and using X86 assembly won't help you if you target the jvm or ARM devices.

Answer (score 1):

In canonical pascal (without keyword Exit) you can emulate return via goto:

```
   function Foo (Value : integer) : boolean;
   label return;
   begin      
      if Value < 0 then
      begin
          Foo := false;
          goto return;
      end;
      Calc();
      Foo := true;
   return:
   end;
```

Comment: Structured programming. Several returns can be acceptable sometimes, even throwing exceptions, but a goto should only be used when any alternative is not acceptable, as it makes the code very difficult to read and maintain. In this case, adding an `else` statement solve the case.

Comment: @AdrianMaire Using an else statement increases the cyclomatic complexicty of the function. Arguably, in the absence of `Exit`, a return label incurs less cognitive load on the reader than nesting, especially if multiple places in the function need an early exit.

Comment: We write code for humans, not for computers: with the exception of efficiency-critical code, code should be implemented for readability and maintainability. The fact that most developers banned the goto (and for good reasons), makes this type of code unusual, and consequently error-prone. 
It's IMHO not true that the cyclomatic complexity is increased in this case: you have 2 jumps + the return in both cases. Additionally, I am not sure that cyclomatic simplicity is a goal, it's neither an indicative of CPU usage, neither a indicative of code readability.

Comment: Cyclomatic complexity is about humans holding the code in their heads. Early exits are much easier to deal with mentally than a bunch of pending if/else/else branches. Which is why even Wirth added early loop EXITs and the RETURN keyword in Pascal's sequel Modula-2.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use either the function name itself, `"result"`, or `Exit()`, but I've only used the `result identifier`, so don't know if the others will work for you:

```
function Foo(a, b: Integer): Integer;
begin
    result := a + b;
end;
```

Hope that helps ^^